# Why does Selenium need a browser to be open i.e. the browser can't be minimised?

Tags: selenium, dom

I've read that Selenium uses the webpage's DOM in order to interact with a webpage. So thought this means that it wouldn't need a browser window to be open. Would like to better understand what it means for Selenium to use the DOM. And why Selenium can't perform what it needs with the browser minimised?

Answer (score 1):

You can run selenium in headless mode. In that case you will not see the browser, you will not see the User Interface. But your application will be run in background.

For e.g in Java you can set your headless mode just by setting chrome options like this:

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("headless");
                options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And it is similar to all other bowers and program languages.

Comment: I can see in your example that the window size has been set. What's the reason that Selenium needs a window?

Comment: Please try it first and you will see that there is no window..All is happening in the background as I explained...Window size is for seting "virtual" window that is used in background.Different window size can cause some issues, so you need to be aware of that fact also.